# Visual Studio produced MSI Installers, Program Files, and Administrator Access

Tags: c#, windows, admin-rights

I have a working program that I am ready to generate an MSI from for distribution. The default install location is `C / Program Files / Foo / Bar` , and that's where I'd prefer it install. *However*, after installing in that location, the program refuses to run unless right-clicked and "run as administrator".

I understand that the program requires administrator access because it is installed in `C / Program Files` (I have an alternate install path that installs it to the desktop that lacks this problem), so I am looking for a way to not have to run the program as an administrator every single time I want to use it.

I had thought that installing the .msi "as administrator" would solve the problem, but right-clicking the .msi does not provide a "run as administrator" as I expected.

Is there any way to make it so I don't need to run the program as an administrator each time, while maintaining the `c / program files` install directory?

Comment: Can you provide more infomation?  Does your application throw an exception?  Does it write any debug information to a logging source?  What are it's dependencies?  Have you profiled it with SysInternals ProcMon to look for any resource location errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the MSI with a setup.exe. You can then right click the EXE and run as Admin.  You can't do this to the MSI because it isn't a program, it's a document ( database ) that's executed by a different program ( msiexec.exe ).

Comment: Running the setup application .exe as administrator does not solve this problem.

Comment: You must be administrator to install to ProgramFilesFolder.

Comment: the program installs fine, but will only run (from that location) if I run "As Administrator". I am seeking some solution where I do not have to run "as administrator" *every* *single* *time* I want to run the program, but still keep it installed in the program files directory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you said the MSI was the problem.  If the program is installed correctly and your application won't run as a regular user then it's an application problem not an installer problem.   What are your dependencies? Are you trying to write a log file or something?   If so, you must write it somewhere outside of ProgramFiles.   What is your program written in?  I'd add that Tag and remove the MSI tag.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when the application tries to write data in a per-machine location (like Program Files or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE). In this case the application will work only if it's launched as an Administrator.

A solution is to use per-user locations for application data. For example Application Data (AppData) folder under the user profile folder and HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

However, if your application really needs Administrator privileges, you can use an [UAC application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).